# how to reload table when certain row is created or delete?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am just learning Vuejs with laravel. and my Delete is Working correctly but when it redirect to index  page after row is deleted that row is not removed until it is loaded..
And for When Category is added new data is not shown until browser is loaded...
This is my Categories Component `

```
    <form role="form"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  @submit.prevent="createCategory" v-if="adding">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="card-title">Create New Category</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Category Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="category_name" v-model="category_name" placeholder="Enter Category Name">
                    </div>
                </div>
               
                
        </div>
        </div>
        
       <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button @click.prevent="cancel" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
        </div>

    </form>

    <div class="card-body" v-else>
        <div class="card-header" >
            <h3 class="card-title"><a  class="btn btn-block btn-outline-secondary btn-lg" @click.prevent="add()"> Create New Category</a></h3>
        </div>
        <table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
            <head>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
             <th>Category Name</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(category,index) in model" :category="category" v-bind:key="category.id">
                <td>{{category.id}}</td>
                
                
                <td>{{category.category_name}}</td>
              <td>Edit | <a @click="deleteCategory(category.id,index)" class="btn-outline- 
            danger">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            </body>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

```
<script>

    export default {
        props:['model'],
        data(){
            return {
                model:[],
                section_id: 0,
                sections: [],
                parent_id: 0,
                categories: [],
                adding:false,
                category_name:'',
               
            }
        },
        methods:{
            add(){
                this.adding=true;
            },
            cancel(){
              this.adding=false;
            },
            createCategory(){
                axios.post(`categories `,{
                    category_name:this.category_name,
                   }).catch(error => {
                   console.log('Error')
                })
                    .then(res=>{

                        this.adding=false;
                    })
            },
         deleteCategory(id,index){
                if(confirm('Are You Sure ?')){
                axios.delete('categories/'+id)
                    .then(resp => {
                        this.model.splice(index, 1);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    })
                }
            }
        },

       


    }

</script>
```

Comment: how do you load the table data?

Comment: sending variable <categories :model="{{$categories}}"></categories>

Answer (score 1):

```
      <table id="example2" v-if="flag" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
        <head>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
         <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(category,index) in model" :category="category" v-bind:key="category.id">
            <td>{{category.id}}</td>
            
            
            <td>{{category.category_name}}</td>
          <td>Edit | <a @click="deleteCategory(category.id,index)" class="btn-outline- 
        danger">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        </body>
      </table>
```

in data add flag:false,

```
data(){
        return {
            model:[],
            section_id: 0,
            sections: [],
            parent_id: 0,
            categories: [],
            adding:false,
            category_name:'',
            flag:false
           
        }
    },
```

in your functions make your flag false in case of success response

```
    deleteCategory(id,index){
       this.flag=false;
       if(confirm('Are You Sure ?')){
         axios.delete('categories/'+id)
         .then(resp => {
            this.model.splice(index, 1);
            this.flag=true;
           })
           .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.flag=false;
            })
          }
        }
```

Comment: table not shown ..... where should i put v-else then ?

Comment: this.model = [ ] before calling api and then check

Comment: No no error.. i think problem is in -> this.model.splice(index, 1); because i have used props['model'] when i used data(){ return { model:[], } the error is model is already declared in prop

Comment: if you are taking your model variable values from parent then just add these changes and your delete function in your parent component and it will do it and your delete function is not correct sorry i should have seen it the first time 
why are you using splice ? there is no need as you are not deleting anything from frontend the ro is actually deleted on the backend and on frontend you are just loading the data again and again everytime there is a change in frontend or some event you perform

Comment: when you get response of api call delete inside it write api call for calling data for table again so that data is loaded and populate in your model variable

Comment: deleteCategory(id,index){
       this.flag=false;
       if(confirm('Are You Sure ?')){
         axios.delete('categories/'+id)
         .then(resp => {
         apicallforgetdatafortable{
             this.flag=true;
          }
            
           })
           .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            this.flag=false;
            })
          }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are overcomplicate this. Just create an API that retrieve all the categories. So after each addition or deletion, then just call that API.